# ros_tutorials compile missing

Tags: ros, compile, turtlesim, ros-electric, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey gang,

Last night I went through the Ubuntu "build from source" instructions for ros-full (although it might be possible I accidentally did the ros-base?) to install ROS onto a Pandaboard ES running Ubuntu 11.10. Everything seemed to go fine (No errors listed during the build process.)

Today I've been going through the tutorials, and when I got to the turtlesim example, I've come to realize a couple things:

1. the install process put ros into my /home/myaccount/ros, rather than in /opt...
2. it didn't seem to make a stacks directory anywhere in there.
3. I'm missing all of ros_tutorials

Now:

1. - I can live with this since it's a single user setup
2. - I'm not sure if it's a problem or not. I did create a ~/ros_workspace and add that into the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in the /home/myaccount/ros/setup.bash.
3. - How do I get the tutorials (and anything else that might be missing between ros-base and ros-full) installed???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30878/ros_tutorials-compile-missing/) by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I just needed to install the desktop-full instead of full. That got me the tutorials that I was expecting.

Now if I could just get the Openni_kinect stuff installed from source... sigh (I made another post for that...)

---

Originally posted by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) with karma: 171 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Building from source does that. `/opt` is where the pre-built ROS packages (the .debs) install themselves.
2. Correct; again, the directory layout for a source build is a bit different. The stacks are just in directories named after themselves.
3. The `ros_tutorials` wikipage will have a link to the source; that, plus proper application of `rosinstall`, will do the trick.

("Proper application", here, means "add the source to ~/...wherever ros is.../.rosinstall", and then run `rosinstall ~/...wherever ros is`)

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2